# Facebook Connect no longer works from my server

Tags: php, facebook

Very recently, Facebook Connect stopped working on my server

In PHP, I use the following code to request the user's info from Facebook:

```
$sSQL = urlencode("SELECT uid, name, profile_url, status, pic_big FROM user where uid=me()");
$sFB_QueryURL = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=$sSQL&access_token=$sFB_AccessToken";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sFB_QueryURL); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$sResponse = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

This worked fine on all my websites for years. Now, it returns a blank response.

If I use my browser to navigate directly to the `$sFB_QueryURL` (from the code shown above), it successfully returns the user's info from Facebook. Therefore, there is nothing wrong with the `$sFB_QueryURL`, or with the  `$sFB_AccessToken` that is retrieved from my database.

Comment: When you say it isn't working, what error are you receiving?

Comment: The "$sResponse = curl_exec($ch)" command is returning a blank string. As a test, if I hard-code $sFB_QueryURL to equal h t t p s://www.google.com, then curl_exec($ch) returns the expected response (the html for google.com). Therefore, there is nothing wrong with the code. This is failing across all my domains, even though it worked recently and the code has not been changed.

Comment: When you debug, is your request hitting Facebook's servers or failing before that? Any chance that the SSL certificate validation is failing? Facebook rotated the certificates used for SSL recently, could you server be verifying them against incorrect CA files?

Comment: Adding the following line solved the problem: 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

Comment: Please please PLEASE don't do that - update your curl library or server to have the correct SSL verification chain - disabling peer verification is a security risk for your app - Facebook distributes a .crt file with the SDK which contains the cert bundle you need to verify Facebook's cert, if your existing CAs don't have it: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/tree/master/src

Comment: Enlighten me: What bad things can possibly happen when api.facebook.com is called after CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER is set to false? Is someone going to hijack the facebook.com domain, and deliver false info about a user's profile? I think not. I wouldn't use this technique for a financial transaction, but in this context, it is much easier to add one line of code that has virtually no risk, rather than have my application crash every time Facebook changes their security certificate without notice.

Comment: "I think not" - that's basically the risk, yes - or someone silently intercepting the traffic between you and Facebook and intercepting your access tokens and misusing them - you should always do everything you can to protect your app and the data of your app's users - in this case your app broke because your server's certs weren't up to date. 

In my opinion it's neither reasonable to assume that a server's SSL cert won't change nor reasonable to pretend that the reasons SSL are in use aren't important

Comment: The URL that you gave has a cert file that was updated in 2012, so that will not solve the problem. I would greatly appreciate specific instructions how my PHP code can access the current Facebook cert file, so I can delete the "CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false" command. I have a dedicated linux server hosted by GoDadaddy, so I am able to execute root shell commands. Once again, very specific instructions will be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please also share any horror stories that you may know, of people who had a bad outcome when they avoided the security certificate of a popular domain like Facebook. Perhaps I need to have the hell scared out of me.